# Convert TRect to TRectF in FMX

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, rect, delphi-11-alexandria

I'm trying to use the overloaded function of `SetBounds()` in `FMX.Forms`, passing `Screen.Displays[index].BoundsRect` as a parameter. However, since Delphi 11 `BoundsRect` seems to return a `TRectF` rather than `TRect`.

I'm looking for a way to convert this `TRectF` to a `TRect` so that I can pass it to `SetBounds()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[@SilverWarior's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72437597/65863) (and [@AndreasRejbrand's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72437123/72438312#comment127967059_72437597) to it) explains how to convert `TRectF` to `TRect` so you can use it with the `TForm.SetBounds()` method (or `TForm.Bounds` property).

I just want to mention that, along with the `TDisplay.BoundsRect` change from `TRect` to `TRectF`, Delphi 11 also introduced a new [`TForm.SetBoundsF()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Forms.TCommonCustomForm.SetBoundsF) method, and a new [`TForm.BoundsF`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Forms.TCommonCustomForm.BoundsF) property, both of which take floating point coordinates via `TRectF` instead of integer coordinates via `TRect`.

So, you don't need to convert the coordinates from floating points to integers at all. You just need to update your code logic to call a different method/property instead, eg:

Pre-D11:

```
MyForm.Bounds := Screen.Displays[index].BoundsRect;
or
MyForm.SetBounds(Screen.Displays[index].BoundsRect);
```

Post-D11:

```
MyForm.BoundsF := Screen.Displays[index].BoundsRect;
or
MyForm.SetBoundsF(Screen.Displays[index].BoundsRect);
```

Answer (score 2):

The only difference between `TRect` and `TRectF` is that `TRect` is storing its coordinates as integer values while `TRectF` is storing its coordinates as floating point values. So, all you have to do is convert floating point values stored in `TRectF` into integers by doing something like this:

```
Rect.Left := Round(RectF.Left);
Rect.Right := Round(RectF.Right);
Rect.Top := Round(RectF.Top);
Rect.Bottom := Round(RectF.Bottom);
```

NOTE: Based on your case scenario, you might want to use two other rounding methods that are available in the `System.Math` unit: `Floor()` or `Ceil()`.

Comment: Just wondering if there's any workaround to write fewer lines of code when using `BoundsRect` with `SetBounds`, I'm using it a lot these days.

Comment: I'd write simply `Rect := RectF.Round` (or `.Truncate` or `.Ceiling`).

Comment: @codeGood see the answer I just posted.